# while installing jre1.8.0_131 returned error exit status 127 and errors were encounted while processing: install-info

Tags: apt, dpkg, jre

i'm using ubuntu 16.04.
i m totally new to linux. i tried to install jre1.8.0_131, and i exported the path, copied the files as tutorial said. and then when i use `sudo apt upgrade`, an error occurs:

```
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 4: /etc/environment: PATH＝/usr/lib/java/jre1.8.0_131/bin: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i guess there's something wrong with the PATH??

Comment: Please edit your above question to include Ubuntu version.

Comment: it's ubuntu 16.04 :]